# Is there a tokenizer for a cpp file

Tags: c++, tokenize

I have a cpp file with a huge class implementation. Now I have to modify the source file itself.

For this, is there a library/api/tool that will tokenize this file for me and give me one token each time i request.

My requirement is as below.

```
OpenCPPFile()
While (!EOF)
   token = GetNextToken();
   process something based on this token
EndWhile
I am happy now
```

Regards,
AJ

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Boost.Wave` offers a standard C++ lexer among many other tools like a standard preprocessor which are built on top of `Boost.Spirit`. Check the following sample in the boost directory:

```
C:\boost\libs\wave\samples\lexed_tokens
```

For example, if you have the following file which is called `main.cpp`:

```
int main()
{
    double PI = 3.14, r = 10;
    double area = PI * r*r;
}
```

You apply the lexer which I named `cpp_lex`(assuming they are in the same directory):

```
c:\cpp_lex main.cpp
```

You get:

```
INT              (#334) at main.cpp (  1/ 1): >int<
SPACE            (#392) at main.cpp (  1/ 4): > <
IDENTIFIER       (#380) at main.cpp (  1/ 5): >main<
LEFTPAREN        (#277) at main.cpp (  1/ 9): >(<
RIGHTPAREN       (#294) at main.cpp (  1/10): >)<
NEWLINE          (#394) at main.cpp (  1/11): >\n<
LEFTBRACE        (#274) at main.cpp (  2/ 1): >{<
NEWLINE          (#394) at main.cpp (  2/ 2): >\n<
SPACE            (#392) at main.cpp (  3/ 1): >\t<
DOUBLE           (#321) at main.cpp (  3/ 2): >double<
SPACE            (#392) at main.cpp (  3/ 8): > <
IDENTIFIER       (#380) at main.cpp (  3/ 9): >PI<
SPACE            (#392) at main.cpp (  3/11): > <
ASSIGN           (#258) at main.cpp (  3/12): >=<
SPACE            (#392) at main.cpp (  3/13): > <
FLOATLIT         (#386) at main.cpp (  3/14): >3.14<
COMMA            (#264) at main.cpp (  3/18): >,<
SPACE            (#392) at main.cpp (  3/19): > <
IDENTIFIER       (#380) at main.cpp (  3/20): >r<
SPACE            (#392) at main.cpp (  3/21): > <
ASSIGN           (#258) at main.cpp (  3/22): >=<
SPACE            (#392) at main.cpp (  3/23): > <
INTLIT           (#384) at main.cpp (  3/24): >10<
SEMICOLON        (#297) at main.cpp (  3/26): >;<
NEWLINE          (#394) at main.cpp (  3/27): >\n<
SPACE            (#392) at main.cpp (  4/ 1): >\t<
DOUBLE           (#321) at main.cpp (  4/ 2): >double<
SPACE            (#392) at main.cpp (  4/ 8): > <
IDENTIFIER       (#380) at main.cpp (  4/ 9): >area<
SPACE            (#392) at main.cpp (  4/13): > <
ASSIGN           (#258) at main.cpp (  4/14): >=<
SPACE            (#392) at main.cpp (  4/15): > <
IDENTIFIER       (#380) at main.cpp (  4/16): >PI<
SPACE            (#392) at main.cpp (  4/18): > <
STAR             (#302) at main.cpp (  4/19): >*<
SPACE            (#392) at main.cpp (  4/20): > <
IDENTIFIER       (#380) at main.cpp (  4/21): >r<
STAR             (#302) at main.cpp (  4/22): >*<
IDENTIFIER       (#380) at main.cpp (  4/23): >r<
SEMICOLON        (#297) at main.cpp (  4/24): >;<
NEWLINE          (#394) at main.cpp (  4/25): >\n<
RIGHTBRACE       (#293) at main.cpp (  5/ 1): >}<
EOF              (#401) at main.cpp (  5/ 2): ><
```

Here is the code, for more information check [Boost.Wave manual](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/wave/index.html):

```
/*=============================================================================
    Boost.Wave: A Standard compliant C++ preprocessor library

    http://www.boost.org/

    Copyright (c) 2001-2010 Hartmut Kaiser. Distributed under the Boost 
    Software License, Version 1.0. (See accompanying file 
    LICENSE_1_0.txt or copy at http://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt)
=============================================================================*/

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  Include Wave itself
#include <boost/wave.hpp>

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Include the lexer stuff
#include <boost/wave/cpplexer/cpp_lex_token.hpp>    // token class
#include <boost/wave/cpplexer/cpp_lex_iterator.hpp> // lexer class

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
//  Special output operator for a lex_token.
//
//      Note: this doesn't compile if BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG is defined.
//
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
template <typename PositionT>
inline std::ostream &
operator<< (std::ostream &stream, 
    boost::wave::cpplexer::lex_token<PositionT> const &t)
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace boost::wave;

    token_id id = token_id(t);
    stream << setw(16) 
        << left << boost::wave::get_token_name(id) << " ("
        << "#" << setw(3) << BASEID_FROM_TOKEN(id);

    if (ExtTokenTypeMask & id) {
    // this is an extended token id
        if (AltTokenType == (id & ExtTokenOnlyMask)) {
            stream << ", AltTokenType";
        }
        else if (TriGraphTokenType == (id & ExtTokenOnlyMask)) {
            stream << ", TriGraphTokenType";
        }
        else if (AltExtTokenType == (id & ExtTokenOnlyMask)){
            stream << ", AltExtTokenType";
        }
    }

    stream 
        << ") at " << t.get_position().get_file() << " (" 
        << setw(3) << right << t.get_position().get_line() << "/" 
        << setw(2) << right << t.get_position().get_column() 
        << "): >";

    typedef typename boost::wave::cpplexer::lex_token<PositionT>::string_type 
        string_type;

    string_type const& value = t.get_value();
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < value.size(); ++i) {
        switch (value[i]) {
        case '\r':  stream << "\\r"; break;
        case '\n':  stream << "\\n"; break;
        case '\t':  stream << "\\t"; break;
        default:
            stream << value[i]; 
            break;
        }
    }
    stream << "<";

    return stream;
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// main entry point
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (2 != argc) {
        std::cerr << "Usage: lexed_tokens infile" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

// current file position is saved for exception handling
boost::wave::util::file_position_type current_position;

    try {
    //  Open and read in the specified input file.
    std::ifstream instream(argv[1]);
    std::string instr;

        if (!instream.is_open()) {
            std::cerr << "Could not open input file: " << argv[1] << std::endl;
            return -2;
        }
        instream.unsetf(std::ios::skipws);
        instr = std::string(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(instream.rdbuf()),
                            std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());

    // tokenize the input data into C++ tokens using the C++ lexer
        typedef boost::wave::cpplexer::lex_token<> token_type;
        typedef boost::wave::cpplexer::lex_iterator<token_type> lexer_type;
        typedef token_type::position_type position_type;

        position_type pos(argv[1]);
        lexer_type it = lexer_type(instr.begin(), instr.end(), pos, 
            boost::wave::language_support(
                boost::wave::support_cpp|boost::wave::support_option_long_long));
        lexer_type end = lexer_type();

        while (it != end) {
            current_position = (*it).get_position();  // for error reporting
            std::cout << *it << std::endl;            // dump the tokenf info
            ++it;
        }
    }
    catch (boost::wave::cpplexer::lexing_exception const& e) {
    // some lexing error
        std::cerr 
            << e.file_name() << "(" << e.line_no() << "): "
            << e.description() << std::endl;
        return 2;
    }
    catch (std::exception const& e) {
    // use last recognized token to retrieve the error position
        std::cerr 
            << current_position.get_file() 
            << "(" << current_position.get_line() << "): "
            << "exception caught: " << e.what()
            << std::endl;
        return 3;
    }
    catch (...) {
    // use last recognized token to retrieve the error position
        std::cerr 
            << current_position.get_file() 
            << "(" << current_position.get_line() << "): "
            << "unexpected exception caught." << std::endl;
        return 4;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [liblex](http://clang.llvm.org/features.html#applications) from clang\llvm too. It only supports forward lexing but it should do.